# DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, deprecation-warning, firefox-profile

First, I want to **use some addons** while selenium controlling my firefox.

So, i tried load **default profile** of firefox in selenium code.

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\y1uqp5mi.default'
default_profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_path)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options, firefox_profile=default_profile)
```

But, when i start the code, a **DeprecationWarning** happened: `firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object`

I search a lot and i don't think it's a difficult problem, but sadly  i can't solve this problem finally, maybe my bad english encumber me... ...

Answer (score 28):

Here is the documentation for this:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/driver_specific_capabilities/#setting-a-custom-profile

I tried this locally and it worked:

**EDITED**: I've changed the code, so there are no deprecation warnings

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\y1uqp5mi.default'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = Service(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\geckodriver.exe')

driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://selenium.dev")

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I copy your code and test it, and got DeprecationWarning again: 
1. DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  default_profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
2. DeprecationWarning: Setting a profile has been deprecated. Please use the set_preference and install_addons methods
  options.profile = default_profile
3. DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe', options=options)
I can solve the third warning, but the other two are the same.

Comment: You're right, I updated the code, so there are no more deprecation warnings on my side.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code changing only the paths, no deprecation warnings but the profile is not loading either, this code does not work for me.
More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474700/unable-to-load-existing-firefox-profile-with-selenium-4s-option-set-preference as I'm not sure if it's just me or not.

Answer (score 17):

This error message...

```
firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
```

...implies that `FirefoxProfile()` have been *Deprecated* and with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) to use a *custom profile* you have to use an instance of `Options`.

---

This *DeprecationWarning* was inline with the following *CHANGELOGS*:

- [*Selenium 4 beta 1*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L118)

  - *Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)*
- [*Selenium 4 beta 2*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L104)

  - *Deprecate using a Firefox profile in Options*
- [*Selenium 4 Beta 3*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L84)

  - *Only give deprecation warning if Profile is being used in options*

---

All the configurations which was earlier set through `profile.set_preference()` now can be set through **`options.set_preference()`** as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s8543x41.default-release'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', False)
service = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

---

### tl; dr

[Setting a custom profile](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/driver_specific_capabilities/#setting-a-custom-profile)

Comment: This doesn't work as expected due to [this bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11028). I found it to work by using the solution provided in the issue i.e. `options.add_argument("-profile")`.`options.add_argument(profile_path)`

Comment: "*Only give deprecation warning if Profile is being used in options*" - I'm not using a Profile, and I'm still getting this warning

Comment: My code: `driver = webdriver.Firefox(driver_path, options=options, service=service)` - and none of my options or service values include anything about the firefox profile

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\y1uqp5mi.default'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
driver = Firefox(options=options)
```