# Error update preferences in Firefox profile: 'Options' object has no attribute 'update_preferences'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I can't update my Firefox profile preferences. If I add options.update_preferences () I get an error. I get AttributeError: `'Options' object has no attribute 'update_preferences'`

How can I solve?

P.S: I wrote this code, which maybe can be useful to the Stack Overflow community, because the Firefox connection with preferences that has been used for years, has now been deprecated, because firefox_profile has been replaced by the Options object and executable_path by the Service object

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
   
profile_path = '/home/xxxx/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default'

options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

options.update_preferences() #here

service = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
  
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: doesn't seem like that would be needed.  Is there a problem with leaving it out of the code?

Comment: @pcalkins options.update_preferences is for making options.set_preference effective. without a preferences update, then the options.set_preference do not apply

Comment: I've never had to use it myself.  (in Selenium 3 anyway...though I do a  options.setProfile(profile) method in Java...) Are you using Selenium 4 here?

Comment: @pcalkins  I did not understand your answer, sorry. However I use version 4.1.0. How can I update and apply those options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`update_preferences()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile.update_preferences) updates the *FirefoxProfile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES* through *key*, *value* pairs. It in the [***`FirefoxProfile()`***](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile) class which is now *Deprecated*.

Instead you have to use `Options` and your effective working code block will be:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = '/home/xxxx/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default'

options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
service = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

> PS: Note that when you use `options.set_preference()` you no more require `update_preferences()`

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571950/deprecationwarning-firefox-profile-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-an-optio/70088853#70088853)

Comment: I get an error. I get the error driver = Firefox (service = service, firefox_profile = profile)
NameError: name 'Firefox' is not defined. Also I notice that you have removed from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options. I added it because using the classic Firefox code with Tor proxy that everyone uses and that has been running on the web for years, I got the error that says to use the new Service and Option modules, because FirefoxProfile is deprecated. The message was "firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object".

Comment: Have added `from selenium.webdriver import Firefox` later :)

Comment: I still get an error, the one I was talking about before: driver = Firefox (service = service, firefox_profile = profile)
DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object. For this reason I was trying to write new code, i.e. the code in the question. It worked fine. The problem was only the update. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Checkout the updated answer. Works perfecto now.

Comment: @DebanjanBDo   I no longer need update_preferences? Because? So if I no longer need it, my code was fine too. What is the difference? Thanks :)

Comment: I have compared and notice that they are the same

Comment: Have you read the footer _PS: Note that when you use options.set_preference() you no more require update_preferences()_ ???

Comment: Yes why? Can you give me a reason? Are you sure?

Comment: @heovan1999 Let me know if [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088853/7429447) answers your question.

Comment: I see that it is your answer and that you are talking about update preferences. But is there a reason why updates are no longer used? I'm curious :). For years it has been used. What has changed now? Thanks. P.S: I voted your answer in the other question in the link and I voted it in this question as well :)

Comment: it's never been needed in the Java bindings... so I'm really not sure what Python was doing there.  I would think each Selenium session would have it's own preferences, even if you are choosing an existing profile.  (Session stuff is usually stored in a temporary folder... and then deleted on exit.... else you'd be changing that profile's settings from the Selenium session.)

Comment: I wish I could have provided more info with those changes but who is interested in what happens under the hood :) give me some time to reopen the _Selenium Chat Room_ we will discuss there. However you will find some more finer info in the [_Reference_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571950/deprecationwarning-firefox-profile-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-an-optio/70088853#70088853) link.