# How to use a existing chrome installation with selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I would like to use an existing installation of chrome (or firefox or brave browser) with selenium. Like that I could set prespecified settings / extensions (e.g. start nord-vpn when opening a new instance) that are active when the browser is opened with selenium.
I know there is `selenium.webdriver.service` with the "executeable-path" option, but it doesn't seem to work when you specify a specific chrome.exe, the usage seems to be for the chrome-driver only and then it still opens a "fresh" installation of chrome.

Starting selenium with extension-file I think is also not an option to use with the nord-vpn extension, as I have two-factor authentication active and login every single time would take too much time and effort, if possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Firefox profile

To use the existing installation of [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) you have to pass the ***profile path*** through `set_preference()` method using an instance of *Option* from *`selenium.webdriver.common.options`* as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s8543x41.default-release'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Error update preferences in Firefox profile: 'Options' object has no attribute 'update_preferences'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088211/7429447)

---

### Chrome profile

Where as to use an existing installation of [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) you have to pass the ***user profile path*** through `add_argument()` using the `user-data-dir` key through an instance of *Option* from *`selenium.webdriver.common.options`* as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to open a Chrome Profile through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280195/7429447)

Comment: Do I need to use a specific geckodriver (linked to my firefox installation)?
With: 
`option = ffOpt()
 profile_path = r'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyz123.default-release'
option.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")` 
the regular fresh and clean firefox opens without any extensions etc. installed.

Comment: For the Chrome solutions I'm struggling currently with the chromedriver.exe, that's why originally I was using the `chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()`. So the questions is again, does the driver matter in a sense that it needs to match for example the version of my browser? If I'm running it with `chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()` again a fresh and clean installation is opened.

Comment: @kayB Ofcoarse, version of matching **geckodriver** is needed to run the execution. See the [compatibility chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447). To add an extension see [How to install extension permanently in geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807581/7429447)

Comment: @kayB For the **Chrome** solutions `chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()` should also work seamless as it downloads the latest [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447). To add an extension see [How to install Chrome Extension using Selenium & Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956655/7429447)

Comment: I now manage with `option.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')` after creating an extra profile called "Profile 2" and `option.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\...\\Chrome\\User Data\\')` that the specific profile is opened. With nordvpn up and running as soon as chrome instance is opened (what I want to achieve), but then the chromedriver.exe crashes: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)" and "unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

Comment: @kayB Sounds like a different question all together. Feel freeto raise a new question with your new requirement.