# Can't run Firefox instance when adding FirefoxProfile to FirefoxOptions against SeleniumGrid

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

NOTE - I am running SeleniumGrid 4.1.0 in Hub-Node mode with Hub and Node running on the same machine.

When I try to run Firefox (ver - 94.0.2) instance using following code nothing happens and Hub freezes

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions
{
    PlatformName = "WINDOWS",
    Profile = new FirefoxProfile()
};

_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(seleniumGridUri, firefoxOptions);
```

Where as if I directly use FirefoxDriver, it works. This works fine

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions
{
    PlatformName = "WINDOWS",
    Profile = new FirefoxProfile()
};

_driver = new FirefoxDriver(geckoDriverFolderPath, firefoxOptions);
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571950/deprecationwarning-firefox-profile-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-an-optio/70088853#70088853) help you?

Comment: Couple of questions here, 1) What version of selenium are you using for your automated tests, 2) Presume you are using selenium jar for hub and node on the Windows platform?, 3) if using the jars can you provide the commands you are using to start the jars? 4) Are you able to provide the full code for your driver instantiation, so it can clearly show what is being imported? 5) Provide the version of your node jar? Please update details to these questions by editing the original question

Comment: @djmonki As I mentioned above in description. 1) I am have tried with both 4.1 and 3.14 version of Selenium C# bindings 2) Yes I am running both on same machine on windows platform 3) I don't see how this is helpful as I am able to run all browsers on grid, only issue is that firefox will not return an instance if I use FireFox Profile. 4) I don't understand this question either. I am simply creating an new blank FirefoxProfile and that is it. 5) node and hub jar version is 4.1

Comment: @DebanjanB - discussion link you provided was very helpful in finding a workaround. Even though I did not see that `FirefoxProfile` has been deprecated for C# bindings, but it is better to avoid its use if it will be deprecated in future. Workaround mentioned in the post solved my issue. You saved me a lot of time. I would like to mark your comment as the solution, but not sure how to do that. Thank you.