# Unable to load existing firefox profile with selenium 4's option.set_preference in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, selenium4, firefox-profile

I have this code that works and loads the firefox profile

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile


ffOptions = Options()
ffProfile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0753x1pz.default')
ffOptions.profile = ffProfile

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Only it gives the following deprecation warnings:

> firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object

> Setting a profile has been deprecated. Please use the set_preference
> and install_addons methods

To resolve the warnings I've tried updating my code to

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


ffOptions = Options()
ffOptions.set_preference('profile', r'C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0753x1pz.default')
    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Now there are no warnings but the profile is not set when the browser opens, it's a blank profile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


ffOptions = Options()

ffOptions.add_argument("-profile")
ffOptions.add_argument(r'C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0753x1pz.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=ffOptions)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: This works but it won't firefox won't open if there's already another instance already open, do you know anyway around that?

Comment: I use a profile created only for selenium (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles), so I can open the instance while an instance of my personal profile of firefox run.
If it isn't enough, maybe the possibility of open multiple tabs may help you.

Comment: It's not a good solution. Selenium normally copies the profile and uses the copy so changes don't affect the next runs. But what you're doing is instruct Firefox to use the profile directly, which makes any changes to it permanent (and affect the next runs).

Comment: Yes, I am using this *without specifying a profile* - which is supposed to work, as @NiccoloM. suggested. But, I am still getting the deprecation warnings.