# how to set specific profile for gecko driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

in this code, i think only --headless is working properly
i tried with -p or --profile "path to firefox profile", none of this is working

```
def initialize_web_driver():
    try:
        firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
        firefox_options.add_argument("-p GPTT")
        firefox_options.set_preference("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", False)              
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing WebDriver: {str(e)}")
        return None
```

Comment: What is GPTT suppoes to be? [Read Carefully](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+specific+profile+for+gecko+driver&rlz=1C1ONGR_esES1044ES1044&oq=how+to+set+specific+profile+for+gecko+driver&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1289j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#:~:text=by%20appending%20%2D%2Dprofile%20/some/location%20to%20the%20args%20capability%2C%20which%20will%20instruct%20geckodriver%20to%20use%20the%20profile%20in%2Dplace%3B)

Comment: it's just a profile name,

add to firefox shortcut will open profile name GPTT, it usually use with --no-remote to open new instances.

```
firefox_options.add_argument("-profile=C:\\Users\\User2\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\qgrlmh39.GPTT") ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using **firefox_options.add_argument**, you must set profile path with new **firefox_options.add_argument** line, if you use profile path same line with -profile -P,etc. it will not working.

```py
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
firefox_options.add_argument("-profile")
        firefox_options.add_argument("C:\\Users\\User2\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\qgrlmh39.GPTT")     
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/to/profile')
```

or

```py
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("path/to/profile"));
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(profile);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);
```

or

```py
profilepath = '/your/profile/path'
options = Options()
options.set_capability("moz:firefoxOptions", {
    "args":["-profile", profilepath]
})
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: thank for your help, i'm researching all problems over stackoverflow and found this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571950/deprecationwarning-firefox-profile-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-an-optio

firefox_options.add_argument("-profile")  
firefox_options.add_argument("C:\\Users\\User2\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\qgrlmh39.GPTT")   

.. look like when using firefox_options.add_argument, you must call it twice 
Eg: First call is for -profile. Second call for path of profile

Answer (score 0):

there are some misunderstandings in the way you're configuring the options.

--headless is an option to run Firefox in headless mode, meaning the browser will run without a visible GUI. This option works correctly for running Firefox in headless mode.

-p GPTT or --profile "Firefox profile path" doesn't seem to be valid options for passing a custom profile to Firefox. To use a custom profile, you should configure it differently.

To use a custom profile, you can do it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def initialize_web_driver():
    try:
        firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
        
        # Specify the path to your custom profile
        profile_path = '/path/to/your/profile/folder'
        firefox_options.add_argument(f'--profile={profile_path}')
        
        firefox_options.set_preference("browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser", False)              
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing WebDriver: {str(e)}")
        return None
```

Make sure to replace '/path/to/your/profile/folder' with the actual path to the folder of the profile you want to use.

Additionally, ensure that the custom profile has been properly created with the desired settings inside Firefox before attempting to use it with Selenium. I hope this helps you